# What is functionality of ArcGIS for Personal (formerly called Home) Use compared to ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-personal-use

I note that ESRI has available an ArcGIS for Home product (for non-commercial use) for US$100 per year. I assume that this is pretty much fully-featured as it seems to have 3D Analyst, Data Interoperability, Data Reviewer, Geostatistical Analyst, Network Analyst, Publisher, Schematics, Spatial Analyst, Tracking Analyst, Workflow .

Anybody used this and can comment on the functionality as compared to the usually expensive product? I never assume anything these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [ArcGIS for Personal (formerly called Home) Use](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home) is a great deal.  I have not purchased it personally, but only because I need a commercial license for my own work.  I know a number of Australians who have purchased it to upskill on ArcGIS for Desktop at home.

The "functionality as compared to the usually expensive product" (i.e. ArcGIS for Desktop) is identical, because it is exactly the same software (and at the Advanced level with many extensions), just with a different license i.e. non-commercial vs commercial.